# Формат печати для numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, print

Есть `numpy.array`:

```py
import numpy as np

MyArr = np.array([4, 6, 8, 4.989123]).reshape(2,2)
```

Нужно его распечатать так, чтобы у каждого значения показывалось три знака после запятой (`4.000`, `6.000`, `8.000`, `4.989`). При таком коде:

```py
print(f'{MyArr:1.3f}')
```

возникает ошибка:

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Как правильно написать печать `np.array` чтобы задать число знаков после запятой при выводе?

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
# Set the print options
np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
# Print the array
print(MyArr)
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы печатались  незначимые нули (для красоты) ? В таком варианте печатает так: 
[[4.    6.   ] [8.    4.989]] а нужно так: [[4.000    6.000   ] [8.000    4.989]]

Answer (score 0):

[numpy.array2string](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html):

`print(np.array2string(MyArr, formatter={'float': lambda x: f'{x:1.3f}'}))`

> ```
> [[4.000 6.000]
>  [8.000 4.989]]
> ```